# Best way to do a "global" GROUP BY a field that is stored as `field1`, `field2`

Tags: mysql, group-by, query-optimization, sql

What I have is a table that has different fields and among them the fields that are called category1, category2. Let's say there is some data stored there

```
(cat1, cat2), (cat2, cat1), (cat3, cat1), (cat3, cat4), (cat1, cat2), (cat2, cat3)
```

A row can't have duplicate categories, i.e. (cat1, cat1) is not possible. Is there an easy way to get an output like this

```
(cat1, 4), (cat2, 4), (cat3, 3), (cat4, 1)
```

What I currently do is

```
(SELECT category1 AS category UNION ALL SELECT category2 AS category) AS tmp
```

and then I deal with this tmp table and group by it. The problem is that I can't find a way to optimize it. So the question is: can you think of any better way to do the select above which would allow me to use indexes? If not, is the only way to do this - to actually create this tmp table and index it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT fieldname, SUM(cnt)
FROM (
    SELECT category1 AS fieldname, COUNT(category1) AS cnt
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY category1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT category2 AS fieldname, COUNT(category2) AS cnt
    FROM yorutable
    GROUP By category2
) AS child
GROUP BY fieldname
```

Comment: I think you need UNION ALL otherwise if a Category had the same count in both columns the counts will be off

Comment: Ah yeah, I always forget that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct category1, category2 
from   myTable
group by category1, catgeory2
```